# Using flexible array member to implement a stack

Tags: c, malloc

With this struct:

```
typedef struct MyStack {
    size_t     size;      // current size of stack
    size_t     max;       // max size of stack
    Item*      data[];
} MyStack;
```

How do I do a proper `malloc` and then `realloc` ? For example, if I do:

```
MyStack* stack = malloc(sizeof(MyStack));
stack->data  = malloc(size * sizeof(Item*));
// ... and later on...
stack->data = realloc(stack->data, new_stack_size);
```

I get the following errors:

> error: invalid use of flexible array member 
> error: invalid use of flexible array member (one error for each item above)

What would be the proper way to do this then? Would this be simpler using `Item** data` instead of `Item data[]` ?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19526457/841108) to a similar question. Read also [the Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) and the [GC handbook](https://gchandbook.org/)

Comment: Why not just `Item* data;`? It's a pointer to `data` items. Also, why `sizeof(Item*)`? You aren't allocating space for pointers, are you?

Comment: `Item` is a struct so I want an array of pointers to those `Item`. Sorry the name is so generic, I can change that to make it more clear.

Comment: @carl.hiass I'm a bit puzzled. You want an array of pointers and then you'll initialize each pointer in that array to pointer to something? Where will the actual elements pointed to be? Can you show us more code -- how you plan to use an array of pointers?

Comment: Just read https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct. Why don't you search for the answer first?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680946/allocating-struct-with-flexible-array-member/12680984#12680984 is related and may help.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm sorry, but how are those books even remotely related?

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks for pointing that out, that's very helpful.

Comment: @carl.hiass: Garbage collection techniques and terminologies are relevant to `malloc` etc.... and parsing techniques use stacks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not want to use a flexible array member for this (i.e. `data[];`). The allocation for the `Item *data[]` is done in the *same* operation that allocates the entire `MyStack` as `Item *data[]` will be located at the end of it.

However this will never work with your stack because *presumably* you want to hold pointers to the stack object elsewhere. When you `realloc` then **all** pointers pointing to the `stack` previously will become invalid (indeterminate to be precise). Otherwise all functions that change the `stack` must always have `MyStack **stack` pointer to pointer as an argument and you can only have one direct reference to it.

Thus the flexible array member is not what you'd want to use here. So yes, it would *mostly* be simpler to just use `Item **data` - or even `Item *data` if the data items would be *contained* inside the stack. This will mean double indirection as above, but it will be much simpler to handle in this case, and you can pass `MyStack *stack` to any functions that modify the stack.

P.S. always expand the allocation by a *factor* instead of a constant amount so that the amortized insertion cost is *O(1)* per one insertion operation instead of *O(n)*, i.e. `new_stack_size = new_stack_size * 5 / 4 + 1` or something...

Comment: thanks, could you please suggest a better approach for the above then?

Comment: just to clarify -- when you say "expand by a factor" -- you just mean doing something like 100 x 2 = 200 instead of 100 + 10 = 110. Correct?

Comment: @carl.hiass yes. It will work correctly in both cases but say if your stack is 1M items, and you realloc to 1M+10 items, it needs to copy these 1M items to a new memory location after every 10 items added and that will be costly. Optimal allocation size discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/q/1100311/918959