# How can you dynamically allocate a pointer in the form int (*p)[n] in C?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, pointer-to-array

Suppose I get input from somewhere and store it in a variable. Pretend the variable is Cols.

I want to make an array in the form

```
int (*p)[Cols]
```

Now, I know you can't do this. So how would I dynamically allocate it to do it?

Teaching me how to do so would really be appreciated!

Comment: *"Now, I know you can't do this. "* - How do you know that? Because that's wrong.

Comment: Add extra `typedef`s in your c code to increase readability. See [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and compile your C code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19526457/841108)

Answer (score 4):

You can absolutely use `int (*p)[Cols]`, it's a pointer to array of size `Cols` (`Cols` times size of `int`, in bytes), you just have to allocate memory for it, until you do, it doesn't point to a valid memory location. The constraint is that the allocated memory needs to be in blocks of multiples of `Cols`:

```
int (*p)[Cols] = malloc(sizeof *p); //prefered
```

Or

```
int (*p)[Cols] = malloc(sizeof(int) * Cols); //alternative
```

In both of the above expressions, supposing `Cols`'s value is 10, `p` will point to a block of memory that can take 10 `int`s.

Usage:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Cols; i++)
{
    p[0][i] = i;
}
```

The above expresssions only allocated space for one *line* of `int`s, but since `p` is a pointer to array, you can allocate space for as many of them as you want (given the memory constraints).

Let's assume you want an array with 5 lines and `Cols` columns:

```
int (*p)[Cols] = malloc(sizeof *p * 5);
```

Usage:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Cols; j++)
    {
        p[i][j] = i * j;
    }
}
```

As you (probably) know this kind of construct is primarily used to emulate a 2D array, one of the advantages is that you can then free all the memory with a single free:

```
free(p);
```

Whereas constructs like an array of pointers, or a pointer to pointer would force you have multiple `free`s.

Comment: cols times sizeof int...

Comment: Yeah, my question was what would be the syntax to do so? Can somebody tell me that?

Comment: Um, I don't think that works since you are not allowed to have Cols there. Cols is not a constant value.... it's from user input.

Comment: @V_S of course you can, where did you get that idea from?

Comment: @V_S Why are you assuming an answer won't work instead of trying it?

Answer (score 0):

```
int (*p)[Cols] = malloc( sizeof *p * Rows );
```

allocates enough space for a `Rows` x `Cols` array of `int` and assigns the address of that array to `p`.  You can then access each element as `p[i][j]`.

To deallocate all you need is

```
free( p );
```